# How do I add a role to the person who sent a message (discord JS)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to add a role to someone who sends a message. I've tried this but it comes up with an error

I've tried:

```
message.guild.createRole({name:"RoleName", color: "#ff0000"})
var memberRole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "RoleName");
message.member.addRole(memberRole);
```

if you have any questions about the topic feel free to ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

I believe [`Guild#createRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=createRole) returns a `Promise` for a `Role`, resolving asynchronously. Therefore, if you create the role in line 1 and you then try to find the role synchronously in line 2, it won’t be under `Guild#roles` (yet).

Instead, wait for the `Promise` to resolve. You can then pass the returned `Role` directly to the `GuildMember#addRole()` method.

```
message.guild.createRole({name:"RoleName", color: "#ff0000"})
    .then(createdRole => message.member.addRole(createdRole));
```